# How to tail truncate some text in UILabel

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

How to truncateTail the text (First 3 letters and dots).

I want to show partial text in textfield and UILabel as well i.e. (First 3 letters and dots). For example Universe should be shown as Uni...... I have searched over internet and found many solutions like some are using truncateTail but none of them are fullfilling my requirement. Need any idea to achieve this functionality.

Comment: you want it to truncate even if the Label is big enough to fit the complete string?  In that case you probably need to modify the string yourself.

Comment: yes i want to truncate. Should i make custom functionality? or is there any existing functionality?

Comment: just use C# string methods

Comment: Write a small function that takes a string parameter called someString and returns something like: `someString.SubString(0,3) + "..."`.  Or, you could measure the control (to estimate how many characters it could hold) and use it in calculating the sub-string length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to tail truncate some text in UILabel

It is very easy to implement it.

```
string oldStr = "Universe";

NSString newStr = new NSString(oldStr.Substring(0,3)+"......");

label.Text = newStr;
```